# Check if variable matches pattern, LUA

Tags: lua

So if I have the variable `name`. How can I check if it matches a pattern?

For instance, I would like to check if the variable name equals a pattern like `text_text`. So words at the beginning then underscore then words. With no numbers.

I really have no idea where to even start with this.

`local pattern = something
  if name == pattern then`

UPDATE** I have tried the following, still nothing is working.

```
local pattern = "a%%sa%"
if string.match (name, pattern) then
    return 1
else
    return 0
end
```

Also tried this way

```
local pattern = "a%_a%"
if string.match (name, pattern) then
    return 1
else
    return 0
end
```

Can I please get some help

Comment: there are only weird ways to do that in native Lua. nothing suitable for things outside debugging. why would you want to do that? which problem does it solve? maybe there is a better solution

Comment: @Piglet I just found this `"" == str:gsub(pat, "")` Could I do something like that? Could you show me an example of the weird ways?

Comment: @Piglet I just want the name to be formatted like First_Last If someone created it like just firstlast then I want to tell them to change it.

Comment: so you want to parse the Lua script through some quality check, not get the variable name within the running script? then string library should solve your problem. it's just a matter of combining some standard bricks. google "regular expressions". there are also Lua libraries that provide more powerful stuff.

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq: Have you tried using [Lua pattern matching](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1)?

Comment: @NicolBolas I've looked ast a ton of different things but cannot find something that would do this. Check if name == letters_letters

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq: If what you're looking for is something to copy&paste into your code, then yes, you won't find that. But if you actually understand how patterns work, you'll find that such a pattern is *trivial* to write.

Comment: @NicolBolas Would this be somewhat close? `pattern = ("a%%sa%")
 v = name
 if v == pattern then`

Comment: @NicolBolas I think I maybe getting closer, this however is not working. Any ideas? or am I wayyyy off `local pattern = "a%%sa%"
 if string.match (name, patt) then
  return 1
 else
  return 0
 end`

Comment: @NicolBolas Can please check out my update and help me out?

Comment: I'll put up a small answer for your particular pattern. but please read some tutorials carefully. you have way to many % in your pattern. you obviously don't know what it does.

Comment: @Piglet Thank you. The tutorial I read said a% equals letters and s% equals space characters, I'm not sure if space characters include _ or not

Comment: no it's %a for letters, not a% read more carefully!  underscore is not a space character.

Answer (score 2):

A pattern that matches any combination of small letters linked with an underscore would be:

```
"%l+_%l+"
```

`%l` specifies any lower case letter,

followed by a `+` which specifies the number of the symbol it follows.

So `%l+` means "at least one lower case letter"

`_` is simply an underscore.

So the pattern  `"%l+_%l+"` means "at least one lower case letter followed by one underscore followed by at least one lower case letter

Please refer to https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html and/or https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1 for all the possible bricks you can construct patterns of.

You can use those patterns in the functions provided by the string standard library. string.find, string.gsub and so on.

If you want to use that stuff more excessively checkout LPeg for example.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
function match(string)
    local string = string:match('^(%a+_%a+)$')
    if string then
       return true
    else
       return false
    end
end

local string = match('hi I'm webrom')
print(string)
```

> output = false

```
local string = match('14545_15456')
print(string)
```

> output = false

```
local string = match('hello_world')
print(string)
```

> output = true

```
local string = match('HELLO_WORLD')
print(string)
```

> output = true

The pattern %a match any letter.

Answer (score 0):

in string patterns in lua,
anything between parantheses will be returned 
also you do % with a special caracter afterwards like a for letters, to match ONE letter
adding + after %a would make you detect THE MOST possible letters , in the pattern before you get to the next character / set of characters
for example :

```
s = "Hello Julia my love ! Here's a hug!"
lovername,gift = string.match(s,"(%a+) my love ! Here's a (%a+)")
print(lovername.." was given a "..gift)
```

In your example, you can do this :

```
var = "hello_world"
if (string.match(var, "%a+_%a+")) then -- In this example, _ will be normal
    print("Valid variable name !")
else
    print("Invalid variable name")
end
```

Comment: So how can I make sure though that if it only matches letters and underscore so someone cannot enter the name **#@a_a**723 Doing it this way, then can enter all the character they want as long as letter are on both sides of the underscore. I want the patter to consist of ONLY letters and the underscore. How is that done?

Comment: You can use sets of characters, a set of character matches any character within that set, for example : [%l0]+ which matches only lower case letters AND the number 0
Adding a ^ at the start of a set means, it will return ANYTHING EXCEPT what's in the set
for example : [^%l_]+ will return anything that isn't lowercase or an underscore.
We can use this to know that the name HAS anything abnormal, , if a string matches something [^%l_]+ it means it's not a valid name , example : 
`if string.match("@hexalOnnn_a","[^%l_]+") then
print("INVALID NAME")
else
print("VALID NAME")
end`